# Terminal Server HKLM registry new key not visible for users

Tags: windows-server-2012, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I need to add a new key on HKLM registry for all of my RD Host cluster. I tried to add manually the key with an administrator account and it's fine. But when I login with a normal user these key does not exists.

Maybe that I need to modify these key on other way?

Thank you,
Salvo.

Comment: `when I login with a normal user these key does not exists` Visible how? If you run regedit as a normal user account the key is not present?

Comment: yes. I need to add a key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\`. If I login into host as an administrator the new key is visible but as normal user is not visible.

Comment: Probably help if you specified what you need to do that is not working.

Comment: I logon on a terminal server via remote desktop and I've add the registry key on the local machine. Afterwards I logged in via terminal server with a normal user and the registry key is not visible.